# SparkPost API suppression-list returning "Method not allowed"

Tags: sparkpost

I am trying to insert an entry into the Suppression List described [here](https://www.sparkpost.com/api#/reference/suppression-list/bulk-insertupdate/insert-or-update-a-list-entry?console=1)

I have tried this on my end, using PHP code, but I also get the same response using their own console on the provided website using a valid API key having the same result.

This is the call:

```
PUT https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/suppression-list/email@gmail.com
```

This is the Request:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Length: 142
{
  "transactional": false,
  "non_transactional": true,
  "description": "User requested to not receive any non-transactional emails."
}
```

This is the response I am getting from the server:

```
connection: keep-alive
x-apiary-transaction-id: 5638e31d13b31d0700ae2b0a
cache-control: no-cache, no-store
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 03 Nov 2015 16:38:54 GMT
server: msys-http
content-length: 45
x-newrelic-app-data: PxQDVFVRCQITVlZRDgcFV0YdFHYaFhEHQxFSERdoYWYcShNDHVEdUlIEG1FIVgsFBFxSVg8IG0RQBBQfQFdQVAFWWlsBXVdTUVcPURNNVQMIRVI8
via: 1.1 vegur
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Method Not Allowed"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you may want to hide your API keys

Comment: Since SO keeps a revision history, you'll need to create a new API key (and delete this one) :/

Comment: sure, I'll change the API key, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add entires to the suppression list you need to `PUT` them to `https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/suppression-list` and the body of the request needs to be like this:

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "rcpt_1@example.com",
      "transactional": true,
      "description": "User requested to not receive any transactional emails."
    },
    {
      "email": "rcpt_2@example.com",
      "non_transactional": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The API documentation for this endpoint is at https://www.sparkpost.com/api#/reference/suppression-list/bulk-insertupdate/insert-or-update-list-entries

As a side note you should make sure not to post the `Authorization` header in your questions in the future. That's your API key - I'd recommend deleting that key and creating a new one.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing... making a PUT request, note that the request is done using SparkPost's own website (in their documentation they allow to test their calls). I'd also tried locally from my dev environment without any luck.

Comment: Are you sure you are PUTing to the right URL? In your example you show `PUT https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/suppression-list/email@gmail.com` but it should actually be `PUT https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/suppression-list` - note that you don't include the email address in the URL. Also the example you supplied shows only a single object, rather than an object with a `recipients` key which is an array of objects.

Comment: I just had to read again, they have deprecated that endpoint: The PUT method on this endpoint has been removed in favor of the Bulk Insert/Update method.